# Indentation error shows even correct indentation in python

Tags: python

See below is my script, i already indented the code using spaces but still it shows error

```
def main(username, password):
    if(username and password):
        if os.path.isfile("macid.txt"):
            num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('macid.txt'))
            if (num_lines > 0):
                print "Number of lines: ", num_lines
            else:
                print "macid.txt file is empty!"
        else:
            print "macid.txt file not found!"
    else:
        print "error"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("example", "password")
```

The error is as shown

```
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('macid.txt'))
            ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: check your first else, Because it seems like indented with an extra space.

Comment: This seems to me to be a magnificent 'off-topic because of typographical error'.

Comment: @TintuMon No. Not extra space. still show error. Just copy my code and run it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler May be it but i am stuck now.

Comment: Check that you are not mixing spaces and tabs, and that you have saved all changes to the file before trying to run the code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I already tried number of times to make sure not mixing tab and spaces. Finally i came here.

Comment: Can you rewrite code again, This time add one line every time and run code. Check you get any Indentation Error.

Comment: Which program do you use for editing? If I recall correctly, back in University my classmates learned Python (and I C) and I remember them saying that there were an issue with their editor (can't remember which) where they had to put 4 or so spaces as a substitution to tabs. Also if you run Notepad++ can you use the "Find" option (Search in ribbon -> Find) and press "Extended" under "Search mode" and then search for "\t", i.e. tabs and see if you in fact have mixed spaces in some places, and tabs in others which I think can cause these types of problems

Comment: run `cat -vet` on your file. you may have non-printing chars. tabs will show as `^I`.

Comment: I copyied the code now shown, added `import os` on a line before it, and the code now works.  So, if you have a problem, you either aren't running what is shown in the question, or you have some mixture of tabs and spaces which is not visible in the question.  (And, I'm sorry to say, the problem is still a typo error — however much you might wish it were otherwise.  It is curious that the error is reported against the line you show; do find a way to look at the blanks and tabs separately.)

Comment: @GustavDanell Thanks..You save my day.. I am using Notepad++ . Very helpful your comment and it solve my issue. you can post it as answer,

Comment: This seems like a good place to drop the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716841/understanding-indentationerrors-in-python-2-7/31717044#31717044 - for those wondering why the issue occured.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Glad it could help! Following your comment, I'll post this as an answer.

Which program do you use for editing? If I recall correctly, back in University my classmates learned Python (and I C) and I remember them saying that there were an issue with their editor (I believe Notepad++) where they had to put 4 or so spaces as a substitution to tabs. Also if you run Notepad++ can you use the "*Find*" option ("*Search*" in ribbon -> *Find*) and press "*Extended*" under "*Search mode*" and then search for "`\t`", i.e. tabs and see if you in fact have mixed spaces in some places, and tabs in others which I think can cause these types of problems

Comment: This seems like a good place to drop the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716841/understanding-indentationerrors-in-python-2-7/31717044#31717044 - for those wondering why the issue occured.

Comment: And yes Notepad++ does show tab as 4 spaces , so that is why the issue occured.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Thanks for sharing link.